# Is it possible to store the state of radio in cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Is it possible? I want to save the state of the radio.. like : enabled or disabled.

```
if(dis == "dis1"){document.getElementById(dis).disabled=true;}
```

This does not last till the code it completed.

Once it is disabled, I want it to be disabled till the code is completed!

Comment: You want to store it at server side (in PHP) or client side (javascript)?

Comment: using setcookie().. if its possible..!

Comment: I would store it with javascript. Are you using any js libraries or plain javascript?

Comment: hey Freakman! can u help me out a little!! ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really nice implementation

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

So in your case

```
createCookie("radio", "checked/notchecked", 30);
```

and then to read it

```
getCookie("radio") === 'checked' or !== 'checked'
```

Source: [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) There are also some other solutions mentioned there, make sure you check them.